# Java - Validation of values in setters

Tags: java, validation, pojo

I think I might already know the answer but have chosen to ask to have it clarified.

I have a simple POJO with private variables, getters and setters.

Some of these are String variables where I only want to allow certain Strings to be used when they are initialised.

My question is simply - Should I put this validation in the POJO - perhaps in one of the setters or should this validation take place elsewhere before the setter is called?

The example below should only allow values `gzip` or `compress`

```
private String compressionType = null;

public void setCompressionType(String compressionType) {

    if( ! ( compressionType.equals("gzip") ) || ( compressionType.equals("compress") ) )
    {
        compressionType = "gzip"; //a chosen default
    }

    this.compressionType = compressionType;
}
```

Effectively setting a default value if someone types in "fred" or something daft.

My reason for asking this is purely because where I work I see this kind of thing quite often, it is accepted here but I'm not sure it should be.

Comment: use an `enum` to only allow these two types, and use the enum as parameter.

Comment: Use enums to do what you want

Comment: Someone likes external Validator, someone like validation in getter, someone do it by Decorator pattern. Is up to you.

Comment: I'd never even considered using an enum. Thanks folks.

Comment: The general rule is to try to make sure invalid values can't even be passed to the setter (as in the case of an enum). But if that isn't feasible, the next best thing is to check the argument in the setter. (And throw an exception if the value is wrong, instead of silently pretending everything was fine, like in your example.) The earlier you catch the problem, the easier it is to deal with. What you certainly don't want to happen is to have objects that are in an invalid or inconsistent state due to invalid values being poked in the field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual way of doing this now `enum` is a first class type is to use an `enum`:

```
private CompressionType compressionType = null;

public enum CompressionType {
    Compress,
    GZip;
}

public void setCompressionType(CompressionType compressionType) {
    this.compressionType = compressionType;
}
```

However, if the validation is heavy you could consider a `factory` or a `decorator`.

Comment: Note you will still want to do some validation in your set-method:  namely, checking for null using `Objects.requireNonNull(compressionType, "Compression type cannot be null");`.  And you probably want to initialize the field to GZip.  These two steps will guarantee a valid value at all times.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, turns out when I said I might know the answer, I actually didn't :)